# Draw and update plotly graph (not notebook)

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-python

I have generated a plotly graph object figure and am showing it using the following code:

```py
area, vertiports = filefunc.grab_env(airspace_path)
fig = visfunc.draw_airspace(area, vertiports)
    
fig.show()
```

This obviously opens a tab in a browser.
I occasionally update `fig` and want to reflect these updates on the graph in real-time. How can I do this without having plotly keep opening a new browser tab. I know that it uses random ports.

So far I have been using

```py
def show_in_window(fig):
    plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='web_files/name.html', auto_open=False)
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebEngineView()
    # file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "name.html"))
    file_path = os.path.abspath("web_files/name.html")
    web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_path))
    web.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Which is closer to what I need but still doesnt let me update the image and I am having trouble with generating a thread for this to run in so that I don't have to close the window down every time.